# How to add Facelets support to Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: jsf, facelets, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.8.2 and would like to add an editor which Facelets support (code completion for JSF tags).

Which Eclipe Plugin can I use? I've tried JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor, but the code completion doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure to add the JSF Facet to your web project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luiggi's answer is correct.

To activate Facelets support, you have to activate the JSF Facet for the project.